# Highlighting the data with different colors in Excel Using C# in Windows Applications

Tags: c#, excel, colors, formatting

I am working with a Windows application. I need to work out how to highlight the data with different colors & styles in Excel. I am using C# to export the data to excel.

This is the code I am using to export a DataTable into Excel,

```
private void btnExportexcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    oxl = new Excel.Application();
    oxl.Visible = true;
    oxl.DisplayAlerts = false;

    wbook = oxl.Workbooks.Add(Missing.Value);

    wsheet = (Excel.Worksheet)wbook.ActiveSheet;
    wsheet.Name = "Customers";

    DataTable dt = clsobj.convert_datagrid_orderlist_to_datatable(dvgorderlist);

    int rowCount = 1;
    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {
        rowCount += 1;
        for (int i = 1; i < dt.Columns.Count + 1; i++)
        {
            // Add the header the first time through
            if (rowCount == 2)
            {
                wsheet.Cells[1, i] = dt.Columns[i - 1].ColumnName;
            }
                wsheet.Cells[rowCount, i] = dr[i - 1].ToString();
            }
        }

        range = wsheet.get_Range(wsheet.Cells[1, 1],
        wsheet.Cells[rowCount, dt.Columns.Count]);
        range.EntireColumn.AutoFit();
    }

    wsheet = null;
    range = null;
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to get the 'Interior' object of the cell or range and set the colour on it.

```
Range cellRange = (Range)wsheet.Cells[rowCount, i];
cellRange.Interior.Color = 255;
```

Excel colours are an integer sequence, so you have to calculate the value for the colour your want. You might find this method helpful:

```
public static int ConvertColour(Color colour)
{
    int r = colour.R;
    int g = colour.G * 256;
    int b = colour.B * 65536;

    return r + g + b;
}
```

Then you can just do this:

```
cellRange.Interior.Color = ConvertColour(Color.Green);
```

You can set the style of the text using the .font property:

```
cellRange.Font.Size = "20";
cellRange.Font.Bold = true;
```

There are other properties like `Color`, `Italic` and `Underline` which you can use to get the style you need.

Answer (score 0):

I realize I am about a decade late, but as a simpler alternative to Simon's custom ConvertColour method, you can also use the [ColorTranslator.ToOle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.colortranslator.toole?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) method which is also in the `System.Drawing` namespace.

For example, the one-liner to do yellow highlighting of a defined range would be:

`range.Interior.Color = ColorTranslator.ToOle(Color.Yellow);`